# iPhone Binary Upload - Bundle ID Problem

Tags: iphone, xcode, bundle

We have our app all ready to upload to Apple for approval but have unfortunately hit a brick wall when trying to upload the binary due to an issue with the Binary ID.

In iTunes Connect the Bundle ID shows as GTYOP2FEGW.com.mycompanyname.myappname (I've replaced some of the values here for privacy but the structure is the same).

When we enter the above Bundle ID in XCode and then try to build the app we get the error that no valid certificate has been found and when we try to select the Distribution Certificate in edit Target Settings the appropriate Provisioning Profile is greyed out saying that there is a mismatch.

After a few hours of searching I found a post that said to remove the GTYOP2FEGW part of the Bundle ID as Apple would take care of adding this.

When we do that the application builds fine but when I go to upload the binary I get the error Bundle identifier differs from reserved bundle identifier.

I believe we've downloaded and installed all the appropriate certificates and provisioning profiles.

In the ZIP file that I created in order to upload the binary I have the .app file and the app icon. Do I need anything else?

Any and all advice, greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have entered the wrong (mismatching or with prefix) bundle identifier on the iTunes Connect web page before trying to upload your app.

Comment: Thanks for the response, when I view the app details in iTunes connect it shows a Bundle ID of GTYOP2FEGW.com.mycompanyname.myappname is that what it should say or should it just say com.mycompanyname.myappname

Comment: Also if we have entered the wrong identifier how can we fix this or do we need to delete the app from iTunes connect and start afresh?